# Converting character to real fails if character consists of an integer (i.e. without dot)

Tags: io, fortran

I am reading a text file with my fortran code. I parse the text file (which contain a bunch of stuff such as names and numbers) and I end up with strings containing real number (they are real time measuraments) such as:

```
string = 1.34
```

I simply write this string in a real number by doing

```
read(levelCHAR,'(f)') level
```

And everything worked great for a month until today, when the number in the input file was exactly 1 and I had:

```
string = 1
```

and the read statement above gave me

```
level=0
```

Therefore to fix this  I added before the read statement:

```
if (index(string ,'.')<=0) then
     string = trim(string )//'.'
endif
```

And this seems to have fixed the issue. However, I wanted to know if I am missing something and there is a more elegant way to do this in one line for example by replacing the format '(f)' in the read statement with a more suitable expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not valid Fortran:

```
read(levelCHAR,'(f)') level
                  1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
form.f90:5.5:
```

You must indicate the input field with such as `f5.0`. Or you can use the list-directed input `read(levelChar,*) level`.

Also, be sure to use the `.0` and not any other number in the `fw.d` descriptor for input. Otherwise strange results are to be expected for integer inputs as they will be multiplied by `10**(-d)`.